# Why django inspectdb skips some ids?

Tags: django

I was running inspectdb on my schema. At first, the defitions are very correct like these:

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    starting_node = models.ForeignKey('Node', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'diagnosis'


class DiagnosisTranslation(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    diagnosis = models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'diagnosis_translation'
```

Then, I added sequences and default values (postgresql) for Ids:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE diagnosis_id_seq START WITH 100000 INCREMENT BY 1;
ALTER TABLE diagnosis ALTER COLUMN id SET default nextval('diagnosis_id_seq');

CREATE SEQUENCE diagnosis_translation_id_seq START WITH 100000 INCREMENT BY 1;
ALTER TABLE diagnosis_translation ALTER COLUMN id SET default nextval('diagnosis_translation_id_seq');
```

I reran again `python manage.py inspect`, and the outcome changes correctly for diagnosis, but not for the other table, it lacks the id attribute now:

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    starting_node = models.ForeignKey('Node', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'diagnosis'

class DiagnosisTranslation(models.Model):
    # Where's the ID ??
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    diagnosis = models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'diagnosis_translation'
```

**Why does Django omits the Ids for some tables and not others ? Especially why does it only happens when I make the id fields autoincrement ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not explicitly define a primary key. Django [defines a primitive key automatically [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields). So in that case a field is implicitly added:

> ```
> id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
> ```

Django will thus omit specifying the primary key explicitly given:

1. the primary key has as name `id`; and
2. the primary key has as type [**`IntegerField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField) (an [**`AutoField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) is an `IntegerField` that automatically increments according to available IDs.

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything !